# hex value 00 to ascii or char

Tags: c++, hex, ascii

I'm coding the adaptive huffman algorithm and i have a problem. Reading a JPG file byte after byte i eventually bump on this hex value 00. Which my program reads as '0'.

Check the picture: http://shrani.si/f/u/Ub/3Yv2Q0LA/napaka.jpg

AS you see, the first two chars are represented with a value before the char. -somenumber 'char'.

In the third case, just the zero is passed trought, but my algorithm doesnt do anything with it, as it is not representive as char. How could i fix this, i need to store also these values into my tree so i can compress and eventually decompress.

Cheers

Comment: `0` is not a printable character, what do you expect?

Comment: And what do you want to do with a binary zero? This, by the way is zero in every base, zero is zero. And there is no "char" for representing a binary zero, don't know what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I see no code here to help you with.  Any sort of "read" routine can read binary data into memory.  That memory can be read as char, unsigned char, int, whatever.  I believe you may have a conceptual problem here.

Comment: Post some code here. I would represent a binary zero as `\0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `char` is a ***number*** (on most systems it is an 8 bit number, but not all).  What you are seeing is the IDE displaying the numerical value with a single quoted ASCII character equivalent.  Not all chars map to a printable ASCII character (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isprint/) for more info).

If the IDE thinks that there is no printable equivalent, it will just not bother printing a single quoted equivalent.  When you put something in single quotes in your code, you are telling the compiler to replace that character with the numerical ASCII equivalent.  Thus the following are equivalent:

```
#include<stdio.h> // C
#include<cstdio>  // C++
int main()
{
  char x = 'A';
  char y = 65;
  if (x == y)
  {
    printf("var x is the same as y. '%c' == '%c'\n", x, y);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("ERROR: var x is different then y. '%c' == '%c'\n", x, y);
  }
}
```

The output would be:

```
var x is the same as y. 'A' == 'A'
```

Comment: I see what u are wanting to tell me. But could u help me, how could i store this in the tree so i could read it back again? If u are familir with huffman algorithm, u know that it stores every charecter he gets or every symbol. So 0 is also a symbol i need to write back when i decompress it. How?

Comment: Huffman is not hard to find with a google search.  I've coded it a few times myself professionally.  Just go look around a bit.

Comment: It is already working with normal txt files, where are chars are representive normally. But with a jpg file and a 00 hex, i'm doomed. I just need to fix this, then it should work

Comment: Show an example in your question and I'll try and answer it.

Comment: It's possible that you are using C/C++ string functions to analyse your data stream.  If this is the case, then you will have problems with 0 as it is usually considered an end of string marker.  Post your example code to allow me to verify.

Comment: Well i have a struct like this:
struct node {
 int weight;
 char ch;
 bool escape;
 bool endoffile;
 string bits;
        node* left;
 node* right; }
I am building a tree and for starters, everything is NULL. Even the ch is NULL but equeals 0. SO when the hex 00 is read, he is represented as 0 and my function returns the symbol as found (and that is root), which is wrong.

I somehow need to be able to insert this 'zero' also in the three, and if it show up again, i need to be able to compare it and eventually found it, so i can increase the weight in the tree etc..  I hope i've given enough

Comment: I've managed to fix the problem. It was a conceptual problem. I added a boolean value to check if this is even a proper 'symbol' in the tree. Eventually it added the zero also in and coded it properly. The images are compress and decompressed withouto any data loss. 

AS for admins, i'm sorry for asking a 'dumb' question, altho the answers helped me understand my problem and i would eventually ask the right question. Thnx to all for answering!